# Missing display panel in intellij idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

When debugging in eclipse, I selected expression and pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. Then I see my expression in display view and there I can evaluate any java code. Is there such view in intellij-idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the exact behaviour in eclipse, so i am guessing a little here, but you should be able to do the same thing in two ways.

Given you are debugging and have stopped at a breakpoint, you can evaluate an expression that is valid in the current scope by highlighting it, hitting <kbd>alt-f8</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd> - or the quick version is simply <kbd>ctrl-alt-f8</kbd>

Or you may prefer to right click on the expression and choose *Add to Watches* (in the *Debug* pane, ensure you have selected the *Debugger* panel, rather than *Console*).

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but I want to have a panel near watches, not pop-up window.

Comment: Ok, well just adding the expression to watches - does that give you what you want, else can you describe why that doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: I want freely edit some code and see it in the panel, not open up window every time and search code there. In other words, I want to have it as it made in eclipse.

Comment: Well to be honest you can't expect IDEA to be exactly the same as eclipse. You have the watches (use f2 to edit them) which evaluate every line as you debug, you have ctrl-alt-f8 for quick eval, or you have alt-f8 for a floating "Expression Evaluation" window on which you can push "Evaluate" at will. Plenty of options here...

Comment: well another difference is that in "eclipse display" window, you can also call methods ( which for instance can change some values, or trigger some actions), create more complicated expressions ( multi lines). I wish to find such function in intelliJ as well.

Comment: You can call methods via the same mechanism. This obviously may change the state.

Answer (score 8):

I'm an eclipse user and I know exactly what you mean by running code in display view.
check this

```
 double shift (or find anything) -> evaluate expression -> Click code fragment
```

check console for the code that I run in debug mode

[image]

Comment: Same result as `ALT+F8` as described by @ikingsteve. `CTRL+ALT+F8` directly shows the evaluation result of the word under the curser.

Answer (score 3):

Found how to restore default layout ! Just push to this button.

[image: just push to this button]

Comment: This is just the **`Restore Layout`** button for the **Debug** pane.  In order to **Evaluate Expression** you have to right-click and use the context menu on a **variable** or **watch**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same behavior as "Display" window in Eclipse, just press alt+F8 and then click on "code fragment mode".

[image]